# Why does an unreadable ELF on linux can be run?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, elf

I understand a script can't be run if its not readable(even when it's excutable) because intepreter need to read it.

But why does an unreadable binary on linux can be run(I use gcc to compile my code into `./my_exe` and set it to 0100 permission)? Executing a binary always invole some reading, right?Then I read this [Can a file that is executable be read?](https://serverfault.com/questions/351672/can-a-file-that-is-executable-be-read), but still have some questions in my mind.

[execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) tells me that the kernel will call `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` to run the program(I use readelf to check, it DO has INTERP segment, which is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`), so I think `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is the user-space ELF loader(which do dynamic linking and mmap ELF into memory). Since I am not being able to read the ELF, I think I should not be able to run it because running it needs reading its GOT to do dynamic linking. It turns out I DO really can't run it like `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 my_exe`. I just get the message that it can't load shared object. But when I run it directly from bash like `./my_exe`, it is run successfully.

My question is: since executing ELF involves `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` ,why my compiled program with 0100 permission can be run directly? `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` shouldn't be able to read it, so it shouldn't be able read GOT and do dynamic linking. So why did I successfully run it directly?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. Can you describe **exact steps** which you perform? E.g. "compile my program into executable /home/me/my_exe", "set permissions 0100 for the executable", etc. Linux treats as executable only those files which have EXEC permission. Without that permission the file cannot be executed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev 0100 permission means EXEC permission for owner and no other permission, I think everyone knows that. I produced an ELF with /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 as PT_INTERP, and set 0100 permission for it, which I already mentioned. The source code doesn't matter. Why can I run this ELF when I am not able to read it?

Comment: Samuel Peter read the third paragraph of my question and read the second link I give about the behavior of execve system call.

Comment: @神秘德里克  ld.so is a part of your binary (library) which is loaded by the kernel for loading other (dynamic) libraries. Why it should read your binary from disk when it is already loaded into memory by the kernel?

Comment: Alex Hoppus Thanks for your reply, that's the only meaningful comment I get so far. Did you mean, when kernel do execve it will do mmap for both PT_INTERP and the ELF itself with proper permission (like make the GOT readable-ly mmaped), so ld-linux.so doesn't need to open the ELF from disk, it just read the mmaped memory?

Comment: Can I think that, ELF with PT_INTERP  doesn't work like scripts (which just let the interpreter do the file opening and reading and leading to the need of read permission),  but kernel REALLY DO some format parsing and file mmap-ing job even if the ELF requests an user-space loader? @Alex Hoppus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ld.so is a part of your binary address space, it is loaded by the kernel with the purpose of loading other (dynamic) libraries. Why it should read your binary from disk when it is already loaded into memory by the kernel? So it turns that ld.so is not reading anything and thus not going through security checks.

> Did you mean, when kernel do execve it will do mmap for both PT_INTERP
>   and the ELF itself with proper permission (like make the GOT
>   readable-ly mmaped)

Yes, you can check it by yourself [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L537)

```
 static int load_elf_binary(struct linux_binprm *bprm)
    ...
 if (elf_interpreter) {                                                      
         unsigned long interp_map_addr = 0;                                      

         elf_entry = load_elf_interp(&loc->interp_elf_ex,                        
                          interpreter,                                            
                         &interp_map_addr,                                       
                          load_bias, interp_elf_phdata);
```

Comment: Of course, this is not where the file is actually opened. See `do_open_execat`.

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis what?

Comment: Checking file permissions is done in `open`, not in `binfmt_*` handlers.

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis have you read anything in question/answer?

Comment: Multiple times. The question is why a file with mode 0100 can be read by the kernel as a target for `execve`. I don't see any answer to that.

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis, it's really not. Read the question. And I know you down vote this answer not because you don't think it's an answer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, it's simply irrelevant.

Comment: "ld.so is a part of your binary" -- no, it's *not*. The rest is correct though.